# How to fix external link markup in a template using anchors

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor-scroll

I purchased and customized a html template www.autoveille.ca but having problems with an added link (href="http://www.autoveille.ca/en/index.html"). The document uses anchors with id's but I wish to add an external link and this is creating issues in other parts of my website. At the bottom of the website, in the "Liste de nos concessionnaires associés" section,it is displaying the list incorrectly and the filter is not working. The only time this happens is when I add the external link. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <img class="logo " src="images/logo.png" alt="">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <div class="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left ">
          <li ><a id="sTop" class="subNavBtn " href="#.">Home</a> </li>
          <li><a id="s1"  href="#.">about  Us</a></li>
          <li><a id="s2"  href="#.">Our  Work</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
          <li><a id="s3"  href="#.">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a id="s4" href="#.">Our  Clients</a></li>
          <li><a  href="http://www.autoveille.ca/en/index.html">EN</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are the issues...you haven't mentioned them?

Comment: please explain "is creating issues in other parts of my website"

Comment: There seems to be some JavaScript that prevents default link behavior on the header links.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more specific, thanks!